# Scaling JNLP Breaks on Resolution Change

Tags: java, spring, swing, scaling, jnlp

We've been using a jnlp app with computers installed with Java 8. We are attempting to make the app appear as full screen, currently it only shows up in less than half of the screen.

Java 8 does not support this so we've updated to Java 9 and added the following properties to our main jsp file:

```
<property name="sun.java2d.win.uiScaleX" value="1.88"/>
<property name="sun.java2d.win.uiScaleY" value="1.4"/>
<property name="sun.java2d.dpiaware" value="true"/>
```

This works quite well in scaling the view, however issues start arising if the desktop resolution is affected in any way. For example, locking the screen and having the screen turn off, or manually changing the resolution or windows scaling, disconnecting\reconnecting an additional screen, or even unplugging the laptop power source will all cause dialogs and popups to only partially display and the top of the app to duplicate visually.

Before:

[image: A single instance of the header can be seen]

After:

[image: Duplicating header]

Before:

[image: Dialog Popup in full view]

After:

[image: Dialog Popup only partially displaying]

I've attempted to update the high DPI settings in java to no effect, both the Program DPI settings and override to no avail. I'm thinking there might need to be some sort of rewriting of the main Java Swing JPanel but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you sure the app isn't simply buggy? ;) Hint: if you get funny stuff happening when resizing, irrespective of scaling, then it probably is.

Comment: @g00se It isn't resizing that causes issues. I can minimize and maximize the app all I want without causing the issue. It's when Windows changes screen resolutions that this bug appears, and it does not happen in Java 8 nor does it happen when we do not add scaling to Java 9.

Comment: OK. Sorry I can't help further

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process